# Modify link target

Tags: php, regex, url, hyperlink

On a given search result page I need to modify the link targets on specific results, like:

- Every `http://www.name.com/company/company` to
  `http://www.name.com/company/`;
- Every `http://www.name.com/company/something` to
  `http://www.name.com/company/#something`;
- Every `http://www.name.com/business/business` to
  `http://www.name.com/business/`;
- Every `http://www.name.com/business/somethingelse` to
  `http://www.name.com/business/#somethingelse`;
- Every `http://www.name.com/portfolio/projectname` to
  `http://www.name.com/portfolio/`;

Please notice that this is a multilanguage website and URLs might also come in the form of `http://www.name.com/en/company/something-en`, where I will need to change it to `http://www.name.com/en/company/#something`, and so on.

I believe this might be achieved using regular expressions with PHP but I am not skilled enough to write something solid from scratch.

Pratical example, change the following links inside the `search-content` `div` (links generated by the wordpress loop):

```
    <div id="search-content">

        <h3><?php _e( 'Search Results for', 'foundationpress' ); ?> <span>"<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>"</span>:</h3>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('blogpost-entry'); ?>>
                    <header>
                        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    </header>
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php else : ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

        <?php endif;?>

    </div>
```

Comment: This can certainly be done in PHP (or even via JavaScript in the browser after the page is loaded, I should think), but first I have to ask ... why are the links on this page in such a format in the first place?  Can *that* be changed?  Better to avoid the problem in the first place than write more code to clean it up afterwards....

Comment: Is it that if the `/first/second/` parts match, the second part needs to be stripped off, and if the `/first/second/` parts do not match then a `#` needs to be placed in front of the `/#second` part?

Comment: Please specify the general rule for that, otherwise, regex is no different than if-else statements in performance, sometimes worse.

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey I'm building a wordpress website and these are the links for individual posts, which don't make part of the website by themselves, they are "pulled in" on a fullpage consisting of several individual posts.

Comment: @varlogtim Exactly. That's basically it, except for the URLs with the language code, where there could be something like `http://www.name.com/en/company/company-en` > `http://www.name.com/en/company`.

Comment: @Cunning I think verlogtim got it right. If the first and second parts match, the second parts needs to be stripped off. If they do not match, then add a #. Exception for the URLs with the code language.

Comment: OK, one problem I see, you might be needing a list of valid "business" and "company" strings, because how are you going to know if "something" is a company name or a "something"?

Comment: Final Question, when you say, "modify the link targets" do you mean you have variables with the first link in it and you need to rewritten to the second? Or, do you mean you need to automatically redirect requests for the first URL to the second one? Can you just add a tiny bit of code where you will be using this?

Comment: @varlogtim I mean I need to modify the link targets on <a> tags in an HTML structure. I'll have a look at your answer bellow. But thank you already for your time and care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tbis is the function:

```
function processHref($input_url) {
    $regex_one  = '#http://([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)#';
    $regex_two  = '#http://([^/]+)/([a-z]{2})/(.+)/([^-]+)#';

    if(preg_match($regex_one, $input_url, $matches)) {
        $domain = $matches[1];
        $first  = $matches[2];
        $second = $matches[3]; 
    }
    elseif(preg_match($regex_two, $input_url, $matches)) {
        $domain = $matches[1];
        $lang   = $matches[2];
        $first  = $matches[3];
        $second = $matches[4];
    }

    $output_url = "http://$domain/";

    if(isset($lang))  $output_url .= "$lang/";
    if(isset($first)) $output_url .= "$first/";
    if($first != $second && $first != "portfolio")
        $output_url .= "#$second";

    return $output_url;
}    
?>
```

Comment: I believe we're pretty close to what I need. Just a matter of modifying the code so I can include it in the php file where I have the HTML structure, is that it?

Comment: Just one detail, in the case of portfolio I need to strip the second part…

Comment: Added the exception for "portfolio" here.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please modify your answer so that the code can identify all the links inside a given `div` and modify them accordingly?

Comment: Diogo, can you update the question with an example of what you will be passing in? By "given div" do you mean a `div` with a certain id? or do have have the `text` of what is inside of the `div`? Definitely update the question though.

Comment: That would be a `div` with a certain id.
I've updated my question with an example. Thanks!

Comment: Hummm, I tried running the code but I get a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL)` in the second line of your code…

Comment: Ok, I believe it's because the input html is generated by php (the links are generated by a Wordpress loop)…

Comment: Include the function somewhere and then call it where ever you need it.

Comment: I've got the code running but there is still a detail missing. As you can see from the question at the top, I also need to strip the last three characters from the end of a translated URL. I believe this should be done before checking `if $first != $second` so that this condition is run properly.